# How to keep the google colab running without disconnecting in 2022

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

I am running my model, but the GPU keeps disconnecting after a few epochs. I googled the solution and I tried this javascript. I right-clicked then inspect the element and then go to console and paste this code.But it does not seem to work. Does anybody know any other code or ways to keep the google collab running without disconnecting

```
function ClickConnect(){
    console.log("Clicked on connect button"); 
    document.querySelector("colab-connect-button").click()
}

setInterval(ClickConnect,60000)
```

Answer (score 5):

Updated version

```js
function ConnectButton(){
    console.log("Connect pushed"); 
    document.querySelector("#top-toolbar > colab-connect-button").shadowRoot.querySelector("#connect").click() 
}
setInterval(ConnectButton,60000);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this I hope this help you :

```
import time
from pynput.mouse import Controller ,Button

MouseClick = Controller()

while True:

    MouseClick.click(Button.left, 1)
    time.sleep(20)
```